# Rewrite output of view summary

Tags: views

I'm trying to display a quick summary of the number of different types of products on our site.

The summary contextual filter does this... but it adds hyperlinks to the items and I can't turn that off, and I can't customise the HTML tags or rewrite the output. Is there any 
to do that?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default views templates for summaries in your own theme. There are two of them, which are located at:

- sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-summary.tpl.php
- sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php

Which one you have to override depends on the type of summary.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. What's the variable I use on that template file?